# When voting to close, is it best to choose the "better" reason or the more popular reason?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, etiquette

Reviewing Close Votes, I sometimes see close votes cast for reasons that seem to me not as appropriate as other reasons to close. In these cases, I am certain the post needs to be closed, so I feel compelled to follow the trend of previous votes, though I question that accuracy of the close vote reason.

I think the most extreme case I could give is a question that had several votes as "too broad" while the question was about Software/Hardware and thus doesn't even belong on Stack Overflow.

With the CV queue now over 100k, I am debating the topic two ways:

- With a queue so high, we should just try to get the post closed and done with, so go with the popular vote
- The queue is so massive that "every little bit" doesn't even matter any more, so for the sake of accuracy, vote against the trend of previous votes at the expense of the post staying open (or open longer).

What's the proper approach here?

Comment: Close - subjective, lol

Comment: A question can have one close vote in each of the 5 different categories and it'll still be closed.

Comment: @jim To make matters more ironic, I disagree with your reason to close. It's an x/y problem, so I guess "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" would be most appropriate. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the close vote tallying. A vote means "this should be closed (and here's why)", not "this is too broad (and should be closed)". Consensus is only required on the non-parenthetical part of the statement. A question could have multiple reasons for being subject to closure.

Answer (score 17):

Vote for the most accurate closure reason in your opinion.

Five votes are needed to close. There is no requirement that they all be for matching reasons.

Comment: On top of that, when a post is closed for multiple reasons, the "put on hold as off-topic" can show multiple reasons, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481198/converting-int-to-ascii-aquivalents-in-c) one as an example.